# How to disable button after ten seconds in android?

Tags: android

I want to disable the button after ten seconds in android.

```
try {      
        btnnplus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        btnnplus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.sleep()` in Main Thead will freez UI.
Use `Handler` and `postDelayed` method to do task later.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnnplus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnnplus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 10000);
```